# RequiredFieldValidator not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a simple form with a required Validator on a textbox.  When I leave the textbox blank and check the Page.isValid it is always true.  I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong to cause the page to always be true.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtVendorTracking" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTxtVendorTracking" 
    InitialValue="Enter Vendor Tracking Nbr" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Vendor Tracking Required." ControlToValidate="txtVendorTracking" 
    ValidationGroup="val" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 

    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="100px"  onclick="btnSave_Click" ValidationGroup="val"/>

           protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Validate(MasterValidation.ValidationGroup);
            if (!Page.IsValid)
            {
                ModalPopupExtender3.Show();
                txtRONbr.Focus();
                return;
            }
          }
```

Comment: Does the text box have an initial value?

Comment: No.  I leave it blank.  The page loads, I search for some data and pre-populate a few fields, leave the rest blank.  I then click submit.  I do not set any focus on any of the remain blank fields either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since initial state of the text box is empty, the problem is here:

```
InitialValue="Enter Vendor Tracking Nbr"
```

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Validation fails only if the value of the associated input control
>   matches this InitialValue upon losing focus.

Since the initial value of the validator is not an empty string, it treats an empty string as a valid input. TO solve thins you need to decide what whould be an initial state of your text box, and set up validator accordingly. For instance right now you should just remove `InitialValue` from the markup - it defauls to `String.Empty`.

Comment: alternatively OP could add `Enter Vendor Tracking Nbr` into the textBox value as a placeholder text.

Comment: I had feeling it was something stupid I was doing.  I don't use Validators much and my new company likes to use them so this is what I get for copying code and not fully understanding how they work.  Thanks Andrei.